# Execute keyboard macro in the current buffer

Tags: buffers, keyboard-macros

I need to be able to parse a string like the following:

```
M-: (forward-word 4) RET
```

and execute it from elisp.

For that purpose I'm trying to use `execute-kbd-macro` and `edmacro-parse-keys` but I'm a little bit surprised as these functions won't be executed in the current buffer (with current buffer, i.e. using `with-current-buffer`), please take a look:

```
(defun execute-macro-in-the-current-buffer ()
    (interactive)
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test-buffer*")
        (erase-buffer)
        (insert "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.")
        (goto-char 0)
        (execute-kbd-macro
          (edmacro-parse-keys "M->") t)))
```

When I execute it then my point moves to the end of the current buffer but not of the buffer `*test-buffer*` as I was expected. But why? What is wrong?

May be I need another way to parse a string and execute it? Which one?

Comment: To be clear, is this an example of a (Lisp) string you want to parse: `"M-: (forward-word 4) RET"`? Out of curiosity, why? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example of a string which I would like to parse. There are can be endless variants: `M-x replace-string RET foo RET bar RET`, `C-c g t C-n C-n C-l book RET`, `C-SPC M-> M-x delete-region RET` etc. I.e. any possible command. I'm currently experimenting with a new package. Purpose of it is the integration testing for Emacs packages. Now I'm parsing an instruction and would like to apply it to another buffer but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: There is not position 0 in buffer, first pos is 1. Beside - rather call functions, not kbd-macro here. Kbd-macros deliver useful short-cuts in certain circumstances, not general tools.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler about position -- thanks! Regarding functions it is interesting idea. I need to give it a try. How to parse function call from a string? And is there any general tool to gain the same as I try by means of kbd-macros?

Comment: @AndreasRöhler I'm sorry, it seems that a function call is not suitable (from my point of view). I need expressions like `C-c g t C-n C-n C-l book RET`. Instead of that I'll need to put a lot of functions calls. I.e. I need something more interactive than function calls.

Comment: All interactive stuff is provided by functions They are also under the hood of these macros. Why not writing (forward-word 4) etc.?

Comment: I agree, with the simple cases it is quite good to use function calls like (forward-word 4). But in case of `C-c g t C-n C-n C-l book RET` there are 5 function calls! I would like to describe that long key binding in another way: `M-x google-translate-smooth-translate RET C-n C-n C-l book RET` (`C-n` and `C-l` are predefined). This is from existing package `google-translate`. Yes, I can call `google-translate-smooth-translate` directly but in that case I'll miss all interaction which I also need to pass.

Comment: Also I would like to add that 5 function calls are not good because I'll need then to repeat them again and again for various scenarioses.

Comment: Please also note that after `M-x google-translate-smooth-translate RET` all interaction happens in the minibuffer. It is not going to be easy to emulate interaction in the minibuffer by means of function calls.

Comment: The code for `M-x` (`execute-extended-command`) parses `M-x` input. The code for `M-:` (`eval-expression`) parses `M-:` input. They parse different syntax. You need to specify the syntax of the various strings you want to parse, otherwise this question is too broad (or unclear), IMO, and risks being closed. "I need to be able to parse* ***a string like the following***" means nothing, unless you specify what "*like*" means here.

Comment: @Drew thank you! I'll try to rethink my question and create new question. You (@Drew and @AndreasRöhler) helped me a lot to understand my goal better.  However my original question was about the issue that I'm not able to execute `(execute-kbd-macro (edmacro-parse-keys "M->") t)` in the buffer using `with-current-buffer`. It doesn't take into account specified buffer but executes in the buffer where my point currently is.

Comment: `(execute-kbd-macro (edmacro-parse-keys "M->") t)` at all works well for me. And I can continue with it despite the fact that this is not general tool. But just that would be great to workaround somehow described issue.

Comment: @Drew in general I'm looking for workaround for described issue but also it would be great to know about other (general) tool by means of which I'll be able to do the same thing as I can do by means of `(execute-kbd-macro (edmacro-parse-keys "M->"))`. I mean the same behaviour. I'm not sure that I'll be able to describe correctly the syntax.

Comment: It's an interactive feature that simulates keyboard presses. Keyboard presses usually go to the active window, so you would have to put the relevant buffer there first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select a window that shows the buffer, too. Here's an example :

```el
(defun execute-macro-in-the-current-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((win (selected-window)))
    (unwind-protect
        (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test-buffer*")
          (set-window-buffer win (current-buffer) t)
          (erase-buffer)
          (insert "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.")
          (goto-char 0)
          (execute-kbd-macro (edmacro-parse-keys "M->")))
      (set-window-buffer win (current-buffer) t))))
```

Please note that, for this to work, the test buffer should not be shown in any window. This is is because each window has its own value of (point). If you wanted to avoid this, you could first check whether the test buffer is shown in any window. But then you have to think about what you want to happen if there are more than one windows (i.e. in which one should the macro run ?).